# How to get the caller Spring bean name in a Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, callstack, spring-bean

I have a Spring service named `EmailService` like this:

```java
@Service
public class EmailService {
    public void send (String recipient, String content) {
        // send out an email
    }
}
```

There are several other Spring services using `EmailService`, e.g. `PaymentService` uses `EmailService` to send emails to customers about their payments and `RetailerReportService` uses `EmailService` to send emails to retailers some selling reports.

I would like to know the amount of usage for `EmailService` and who are using it. Specifically, I want a bar chart that says "`PaymentService` called `EmailService` for 300 times a day" and "`RetailerReportService` called `EmailService` for 20 times a day".

Therefore, I want to add some code inside `EmailService` to monitor who are calling it. The first thing came to my mind is to retrieve the call stack with `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`. However, since my application is using Spring framework, the call stack is full of proxy classes like `org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint()` or `sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0()`. Still, I can traverse the call stack and filter out unwanted classes by package names, but it would look ugly.

I would like to know if Spring provides a way to retrieve the caller Spring bean's name, so that I can use it inside `EmailService` to get names like `paymentService` or `retailerReportService`. Thank you.

Comment: As Spring is all about separation of concerns and loose coupling, why not **consider** going the **AOP** way? Create an `@Aspect` class, create a method (`@Around, @Before or @After`) and then define a pointcut that points to the EmailService class' method or even better, consider creating a custom annotation class to handle your needs. This solution could also very easily scale and monitor other service classes that you might have.

Comment: @ShashwatKaundinya Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to retrieve the caller's name from the `ProceedingJoinPoint` in a @Aspect class. I can only find the callee's name. Could you please give me some hints about how to retrieve the caller's name in `ProceedingJoinPoint`? Thanks!

Comment: You could use `proceedingJoinPoint.getThis().getClass().getName()` to get the caller to your target. You could also match the method signature by leveraging Reflection now that you have a reference to your caller class.

Comment: I tried `proceedingJoinPoint.getThis().getClass().getName()`, but I got `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy200`. How do I get the "real" caller, e.g. `PaymentService` and `RetailerReportService`?